# Как правильно отрисовать компонент AgGridVue?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Я использую Vue3 + Composition API + TypeScript + TSX + Ag Grid community.
Вот мой компонент, который отрисовывает AgGridVue:

```
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';

import {AgGridVue} from 'ag-grid-vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'GridReportComponent',
    render() {
        // const columnDefs = [
        //     {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
        //     {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
        //     {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
        // ];
        //
        // const rowData = [
        //     {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
        //     {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
        //     {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
        // ];
        return (
            <div class="grid-main">
                <AgGridVue />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Получаю ошибку TS:

```
'AgGridVue' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'AgGridVue' is not a valid JSX element.
    Property '$props' is missing in type 'AgGridVue' but required in type 'ElementClass'.
    19 |         return (
    20 |             <div class="grid-main">
  > 21 |                 <AgGridVue />
       |                  ^^^^^^^^^
    22 |             </div>
    23 |         )
    24 |     }
```

И в консоле:

```
AgGridVue.js?1283:6 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at extendStatics (AgGridVue.js?1283:6)
    at __extends (AgGridVue.js?1283:9)
    at eval (AgGridVue.js?1283:27)
    at eval (AgGridVue.js?1283:193)
    at Module../node_modules/ag-grid-vue/lib/AgGridVue.js (chunk-vendors.js:117)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js?401b:6)
    at Object../node_modules/ag-grid-vue/main.js (chunk-vendors.js:165)
```

Кто сталкивался, как это можно решить ?

Answer (score 0):

Вызывать его нормально, как требует документация:

```
<ag-grid-vue style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :rowData="rowData">
</ag-grid-vue>
```